# How does one prove that $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-groups, irreducible-polynomials

Where $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the finite field with two elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any thoughts? have you, say, tried to find a root?

Comment: I see, considering trying a root and the answers below, if I show there are no linear roots (by exhaustively testing each linear element over the field), then it is irreducible, otherwise it would have a linear root.

Comment: Right.  You can do this one mentally.

Comment: So i've got the factors: x + 1 and x, so possible roots to try would be -1 and 0. Let f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1. f(-1) = -1 + 1 + 1 = 1, and f(0) = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1, neither of which equal to 0. Would that be correct?

Comment: Not following.  There are only two elements in $\mathbb F_2$, namely $0,1$.  There is no $-1$ (it's the same as $1$).  So you just need to compute $f(1)=1,f(0)=1$ to see that neither are roots.

Comment: Oh I see, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: It is enough to show that it does not have roots since a reduced polynomial of degree 3 has a root.

Answer (score 3):

Assume it is reducible. Since it has degree $3$, one of the factors would have to be linear, therefore there would be a root of this polynomial. Now check, by plugging in directly, whether any of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a root.